# SQLConnection.StateChange Event AddHandler using StateChangeEventHandler vs AddressOf

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

What are the differences, side effects, and/or preferences of these 2 different ways of adding an event handler for the `SQLConnection.StateChange` event?  Since `AddressOf` creates a delegate (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx), and `StateChangeEventHandler` is a delegate as well, example 2 seems to just be creating nested delegates, but I'm guessing that there is some nuance that I'm missing.

From my testing they appear to work the same using either example 1 or 2.  Neither throw an exception when attempting to call AddHandler more than once (my first assumption was that calling example #1 would throw an error if attempting to call AddHandler a second time since it would be adding the same reference, as where example 2 would not since it would be a new delegate instance; however, they both succeed without an exception).

**Example 1:** Using only `AddressOf`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx

```
AddHandler conn.StateChange, AddressOf OnConnectionStateChange
```

**Example 2:** Using an instance of the `StateChangeEventHandler` delegate as listed here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
AddHandler conn.StateChange, New StateChangeEventHandler(AddressOf OnConnectionStateChange)
```

Also, is there a need to remove this handler prior to dispose/end of the `using` block via `RemoveHandler`, or will `SQLConnection.Dispose` take care of that for you?  I'm not sure how you would remove the event handler if using the `StateChangeEventHandler` in example #2 below from the MSDN site, since the instance of `StateChangeEventHandler` delegate is not stored in a local variable, so you have no reference of the handler to remove (you would have to do something similar to Example #4).

**Example #3:** `RemoveHandler` using just `AddressOf`

```
    Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("...")
        AddHandler conn.StateChange, AddressOf OnConnectionStateChange
        conn.Open()
        '...do work here...
        conn.Close()
        'Then do i need this?
        RemoveHandler conn.StateChange, AddressOf OnConnectionStateChange
    End Using
```

**Example #4:** `RemoveHandler` using the `StateChangeEventHandler`

```
    Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("...")
        Dim myHandler As StateChangeEventHandler = New StateChangeEventHandler(AddressOf OnConnectionStateChange)
        AddHandler conn.StateChange, myHandler
        conn.Open()
        '...do work here...
        conn.Close()
        'Then do i need this?
        RemoveHandler conn.StateChange, myHandler
    End Using
```

NOTE: I tagged as C# as well since the MSDN documentation also lists the same scenario for the C# example:

```
connection.StateChange  += new StateChangeEventHandler(OnStateChange);
```

vs.

```
connection.StateChange  += OnStateChange;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74wy9422(v=vs.90).aspx) which mentions that AddressOf is simply short-hand for New EventHandler(AddressOf fn).

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf Button1_Click)
' The following line of code is shorthand for the previous line. 
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Me.Button1_Click
```

and it also states:

> You can use the shorthand way of creating delegates anywhere the
>   compiler can determine the delegate's type by the context

So in most cases, using `New SomeEventHandlerType(AddessOf x)` or just `AddressOf x` accomplishes the same thing.  In the case of `SQLConnection.StateChange`, the event is Declared as `Public Event StateChange As StateChangeEventHandler`, so the compiler knows the correct delegate type to use, and `AddressOf` is smart enough to use the correct delegate type automatically for you.  There is no need to use `New StateChangeEventHandler(AddressOf OnConnectionStateChange)`, but it can be used for code clarity to show that this is not the generic EventHandler delegate type, and that it uses a custom EventArgs type.

As far as unsubscribing, to be absolutely certain to avoid resource leaks, you should remove event handler references before disposing of the subscriber object. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.120).aspx which states:

> In order to prevent resource leaks, you should unsubscribe from events
>   before you dispose of a subscriber object. Until you unsubscribe from
>   an event, the multicast delegate that underlies the event in the
>   publishing object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates
>   the subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds
>   that reference, garbage collection will not delete your subscriber
>   object.

In actual practice, I've seen very few examples that do this (even in the MSDN "How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx).  GC will take care of removing event references on the publisher when it is finalized.  However, if you have scenarios where the **publisher** can live much longer than the **subscriber**, you will need to make sure the remove the event references manually.  In the SQLConnection example, the connection object (i.e. the **publisher** of the StateChange event) has a short lifetime, so the `RemoveHandler` is arguably not needed.   See this post for more details: [.NET object events and dispose / GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507632/net-object-events-and-dispose-gc)