# Is it necessary to remove events when disposing an object?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove handlers on disposing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460525/remove-handlers-on-disposing-object)

I have some code which dynamically adds and removes `Controls` to/from a `Form`.  The controls are stored in a collection owned by the form.  When removing controls the code goes through and disposes of them as follows

```
   if (node != null && !node.IsDisposed)
   {
      node.Resize -= docNode_Resize;
      node.DocumentRefreshRequested -= docNode_DocumentRefreshRequested;
      node.Dispose();
   }
```

Is the removing of events part necessary?  Seems like `Dispose()` is sufficient.

Comment: This is been asked many, many, many times. https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+dispose+object+remove+event+handlers&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+dispose+object+remove+event+handlers&gs_l=hp.3...2009.14157.0.15027.86.71.12.0.0.0.178.8365.13j58.71.0.les%3Beqn%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D1%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue..0.0...1c.1.S3iqf646p8Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=7e599a8195490a44&biw=1440&bih=799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was asked **So many times**.

No, you do not need that, unless:

- events are with static subscriptions
- massive quantity of events and subscription (from personal expirience, unsubscribing benefits in terms of memory consuption)